# Get the most commented posts for the last x days

Tags: popular-posts

I want to get the most commented posts for the last x days,I have the following code:

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;
  $weekstart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-12 days'));
  $query = $wpdb->prepare("
  SELECT comment_post_id, count( comment_post_id ) AS c, SUBSTRING( comment_date,1,    5     ) AS d
 FROM        $wpdb->comments
 WHERE       (comment_date >= %s)
 GROUP BY comment_post_id
 ORDER BY c DESC, d DESC ",$weekstart);

 $col_ids = $wpdb->get_col($query);
 if ($col_ids) {
 $postids = implode($col_ids,', ');
 echo $postids;

function filter_orderby($orderby = '') {
global $postids;
$orderby = " FIELD(ID,$postids )";
echo $orderby;
return $orderby;
}

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'filter_orderby');  
?>
```

I want to filter the posts by id,the problem is that echoing $orderby (for testing) would return this:
FIELD(ID, )
and not the actual order, the FIELD is not recognized and $postids is empty. What am i missing here ? How can I get this to work properly ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `orderby` parameter of `WP_Query`. If you set it to `comment_count`, you can get the most popular. You will probably need to filter the `WHERE` parameter to set your date on the query (unless you want the last week or the last month or something simple like that) though.